# Fetch request renders undefined in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Vanilla JS code inside my html block

```
<label for="weather"></label><input value="copenhagen" type="text" id="weather" placeholder="Enter your name to get weather">
<button onClick="getValue()">Submit</button>

<div id="weather-box"></div>
<script>
    function getValue() {
        const form = document.getElementById('weather').value;
        const weatherBox = document.getElementById('weather-box')
        console.log(form);
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/weather?city=${form}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    weatherBox.innerHTML = `
                    weather is ${data.summary}
                    temperature is ${data.temperature}
                    `
                })
    }


</script>
```

the problem is that, even though the data is logged out correctly, it gives undefined inside the rendered html code.

Why is this happening, and how cani fix it?

EDIT:

I have added the output from the `console.log(data)`

[image]

Comment: Can you share the results of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: "it gives undefined" — Does it display the string "undefined" or does it display nothing at all?

Comment: i have added the console.log from the data

Comment: It looks like your `data` has a property `data` with the results you want.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: it displays `undefined` as a string inside the html (makes sense?)

Comment: It looks like `data` has a `data` property where the content you expect can be found.

Comment: So this would be `data.data.summary`

Comment: To make it easier for yourself; Rename argument to `response`; then it would be `response.data.summary`, or use object destruction

Comment: @Pointy yes correct.. i did not pay attention to the actual json response... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log(data)` indicates that your response (`data`) has a property *also* called `data`, which holds the information you want.

You could access it via `data.data.summary` (or better yet, rename your response to something like `response`).

An alternative would be to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value) it:

```
.then(({data}) => {
  weatherBox.innerHTML = `
  weather is ${data.summary}
  temperature is ${data.temperature}
  `
})
```

Comment: I like The deconstruct approach.. alternativly rensning from The server response Would be better, but +1 for that!

Comment: If you don't plan on accessing any properties of the response *other* than `data`, I personally find the destructuring approach a bit cleaner and easier, but to each their own :)